# database recommendation for an offline html cookbook

Tags: html, database

I am currently planning to transfer my cooking recipies from a word document into an offline webpage. I have a (very) basic understanding of html, css and javascript, but never really got in contact with a database.

Can you recommend any database that I can use for my project?
My requirements are:

- ideally future-proof -> widespread usage, state of the art and exportable for future use
- broad applicability (maybe useable in future projects), not just for cooking books
- no php, since the page is offline a server should no be necessary
- no need for a fancy user interface. I would prefer to just enter and change the data directly in the database, like entering text in excel. I do not want to use commands like "update" or "insert" to add data.

I read about Excel, MS-Access, mySQL, MariaDB, …
Can anyone recommend a database for my purpose? This would really help me out! I am lost in the jungle of opportunities.

Thank you in advance
Best regards
REn0

Edit: I uploaded an image to clarify my idea. Unfortunatly stackoverflow does not allow me to embed it into the post, thats why I only posted the link

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nvx1.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the tenets of Rails is you shouldn't really care what database you're using: that's all abstracted for you. I know it's kind of diverging from your skillset, but Rails would be a great approach for an application like this, especially if you want to deploy to a server instead of running it locally down the road.

Check out some 12 in 12 tutorials by Mackenzie Child, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QhdzE1yNs-0

Comment: I looked at rails and it has all the functions I need, except for one backdraw: If I saw it correctly I need a server for it (localhost). If it is in any way possible I would like to avoid using a server. It should work by just opening the firefox or chrome browser with no further action necessary. I do not really care for any security warnings, because all files are fully under my control and I do not plan to post this webpage to the internet. Is there any possibility to work around the need of a server, local or hosted? Best regards

Comment: @REn0 localhost is a hostname that simply means this computer. It doesn't require any additional setup aside from initializing your Rails environment. It might sound complicated at the surface, but it's not. I would still recommend you checkout the post above and approach the build in a similar way. Without a database, you would be hardcoding the recipes into the HTML; hardcoding isn't very maintainable. If you think this has helped at all, hit that little checkmark beside my post.